# Matplotlib hiding scatters behind voxels

Tags: python, matplotlib, voxel

I am trying to visualize a 3D parameter space where I am confident about my parameters with voxels, and where my estimated parameters are with scatters. The goal is to clearly see whether or not the parameters are within this space.

Even though the voxels are not see-through, the scatters are plotted 'on top' of the voxel:

[image: voxel_scatter]

I would like the voxel to at least hide the scatters behind it, but preferably I would like to make the voxels see-through (e.g. alpha 0.5), with the scatters changing color depending on how much voxel the light has travelled through. Is something like this even possible with matplotlib?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 100)) * 5

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.scatter(x, y, z)

cube = np.mgrid[0:1:0.2,0:1:0.2] > 0.5
ax.voxels(cube, edgecolor='k', linewidth=0.)
```

Comment: This is a known issue with matplotlib 3D plotting. See here: https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles
The suggestion there is to try using mayavi instead

Comment: @tmdavison, thanks I did not know that. I'll move to mayavi then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tmdavison pointed out, matplotlib is quite limited for these kind of things. Here is my example using **mayavi** instead.
[image]

```
import mayavi.mlab
import np as np


x, y, z = np.random.random((3, 100)) * 5
xx, yy, zz = np.where(np.mgrid[0:1:0.2,0:1:0.2] > 0.5)

nodes = mayavi.mlab.points3d(x, y, z,
                             color=(1, 0, 0),
                             scale_factor=0.1)

mayavi.mlab.points3d(xx, yy, zz,
                     mode="cube",
                     color=(0, 1, 0),
                     scale_factor=1)

mayavi.mlab.show()
```